# using jq select operation on json arrays

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

I have 2 json arrays: data1 and data2. 
I'm trying to merge the 2 json arrays into one json, using jq.
for this: I'm fetching the shared property "region" from the data1, and trying to find the matching one in data2.
Yet, jq's select fails to work with the parameter I pass, but it does work with any specific value.

```
data1='[ 
 {"domain": "domain1", "region": "region1"}, {"domain": "domain2","region": "region2"}, { "domain": "domain3", "region": "region3"} ]'

data2='[ 
 {"region": "eustaging1", "secret": "s1"}, {"region": "eustaging2", "secret": "s2"}, { "region": "eustaging2", "secret": "s3"}]'

for k in $(jq -c '.[]' <<< "$data1"); do
    crgn=$(jq '.region' <<< $k)
    # select with parameter not working :(
    matching_obj=$(jq -c  '.[] | select(.region=="$crgn") ' <<< "$data2")
    echo "current region is $crgn" 
    echo "matching object is $matching_obj"
done
```

output:

```
 current region is "region1"
 matching object is
 current region is "region2"
 matching object is
 current region is "region3"
 matching object is
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. What is the desired output?  Also, please note that , based on the description of the problem, it would seem that a jq-only solution might be best (by far).

Answer (score -2):

I had to use single-quotes. not double quotes. and no need to named parameters.

```
for k in $(jq -c '.[]' <<< "$data1"); do
    current_region=$(jq '.region' <<< $k)
    matching_obj=$(jq -c '.[] | select(.region=='$current_region')' <<< "$data2")
    echo "matching_obj is $matching_obj"
    echo "current region is $current_region" 
done
```